# Open layers features not disappearing after vectorSource.clear() and refresh in React

Tags: reactjs, openlayers

Using OpenLayers 7.1.0 and React 18.2.0, I have a map with some region boxes displayed on a vector layer using GeoJSON data handed in as a prop to my `VectorLayer` component.

When the `features` prop changes, a useEffect is fired which is supposed to be clearing the old features off the map and rendering only the new ones. New features are rendered as expected, but they appear on top of the old ones which are not being removed.

After attempting to remove the old features by calling `clear()` and `refresh()` on the source and `renderSync()` on the map, and before adding the new features to the source, `console.log(vectorLayer.GetSource().GetFeatures())` shows an empty array but the old features are still visible. I've tried creating a whole new source and even tried creating a whole new layer without success.

I referenced this example to set up the structure of the map context and the basic layers:
https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-incorporate-openlayers-maps-into-react-65b411985744

**VectorLayer.js:**

```js
import {useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import MapContext from "../MapContext";
import OLVectorLayer from 'ol/Layer/Vector';
import VectorSource from "ol/source/Vector";
import {createBox} from "ol/interaction/Draw";
import {Draw} from "ol/intraction";
import {GeoJSON} from "ol/format";

const VectorLayer = ({source, style, zIndex = 0, canDraw, onShapeDrawn, features}) => {
    const {map} = useContext(MapContext);
    //const [vectorLayer, setVectorLayer] = useState(null);
    let vectorSource = new VectorSource({wrapX: true});
    let vectorLayer = new OLVectorLayer({
        source: vectorSource,
        style
    });

    const drawBox = new Draw({
        source: vectorSource,
        type: 'Circle',
        geometryFunction: createBox(),
    });

    // "Constructor"
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!map) return;

        // let vectorLayer = new OLVectorLayer({
        //     source: vectorSource,
        //     style
        // });

        map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
        vectorLayer.setZIndex(zIndex);

        if( canDraw )
        {
            map.addInteraction(drawBox);

            if( onShapeDrawn != null ) {
                drawBox.on('drawend', (e) => {
                    onShapeDrawn(e);
                })
            }
        }

        //setVectorLayer(vectorLayer);

        return () => {
            if (map) {
                map.removeLayer(vectorLayer);
            }
        }
    }, [map]);

    // update map if features prop changes
    useEffect( () => {
        console.log('new # of features');
        console.log(features?.features?.length);
        if (features?.features?.length) { // may be empty on first render
            // vectorLayer.getSource().clear();
            // vectorLayer.getSource().refresh();
            // map.renderSync();
            // console.log('old source features after clear and refresh');
            // console.log(vectorLayer.getSource().getFeatures());
            map.removeLayer(vectorLayer);

            // let featureSource = new VectorSource({
            //     wrapX: true
            // })

            // featureSource.addFeatures(new GeoJSON().readFeatures(features,
            //     {dataProjection:'EPSG:4326', featureProjection:'EPSG:4326'}));

            // vectorLayer = new OLVectorLayer({
            //     source: featureSource,
            //     style
            // });
            vectorSource.clear();
            vectorSource.refresh()
            vectorSource.addFeatures(new GeoJSON().readFeatures(features,
                {dataProjection:'EPSG:4326', featureProjection:'EPSG:4326'}));

            // set features to map
            // vectorLayer.setSource(featureSource);
            map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
            vectorLayer.setZIndex(zIndex);
            map.renderSync();
        }

    },[features])

    // Enabled/Disabled draw interaction when canDraw bool prop changes
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!map) return;
        console.log(`vector layer canDraw: ${canDraw}`);
        if( canDraw )
        {
            map.removeLayer(vectorLayer);
            map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
            vectorLayer.setZIndex(zIndex);

            map.addInteraction(drawBox);

            if( onShapeDrawn != null ) {
                drawBox.on('drawend', (e) => {
                    onShapeDrawn(e);
                })
            }
        } else {
            console.log('removing draw interaction');
            map.getInteractions().pop();
        }
    }, [canDraw]);

    return null;
}

export default VectorLayer;
```

I've just left in the commented-out code to show a few different things I have tried. If it's a bit confusing to look through I'd be happy to clean it up some more.

Comment: Interesting topic. To my understanding, `vectorSource.clear` is correct, see [docs](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_Vector-VectorSource.html#clear). Your `features?.features?` check looks weird. Can you reproduce the behavior with n features on the map, just trying to clear them?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about `vectorSource.clear()` being incorrect.

The `features?.features?` check is a little strange, but that's because the prop is called `features` and I'm passing in a GeoJSON feature collection, meaning I have to grab `.features` from it to get the actual region data.

I have a basic plain html/js version where I tested to make sure `.clear()` was functioning properly and it works there, but for some reason not in React. I've even logged the array returned by `getFeatures()` after calling it in React, and it returns an empty array, but they don't disappear.

Comment: I've realized that calling `getFeatures()` on the source even before clearing it still returns an empty array. Looking at the documentation, this should be returning a list of all the features currently in the source, but it's not returning anything despite the fact that there are features being displayed on the map.

Comment: Are you sure your vector source is not out of sync?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply, thought I had already come back and updated this!

I was able to resolve the issue by restructuring the code of `VectorLayer.js` to ensure that the source, layer, and interactions were only being created once. The issue was caused by their `ol_uid` being regenerated on new renders.

**VectorLayer.js**

```js
import {useContext, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import MapContext from "../MapContext";
import OLVectorLayer from 'ol/Layer/Vector';
import VectorSource from "ol/source/Vector";
import {createBox} from "ol/interaction/Draw";
import {Draw} from "ol/interaction";
import {GeoJSON} from "ol/format";

const VectorLayer = (props) => {
    const {style, zIndex = 0, canDraw, onShapeDrawn, featureCollection} = props;
    const {map} = useContext(MapContext);

    const [isInstantiated, setIsInstantiated] = useState(false);

    const [vectorLayer, setVectorLayer] = useState(null);
    const [vectorSource, setVectorSource] = useState(null);
    const [drawBox, setDrawBox] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!map || isInstantiated) return;

        setVectorSource(new VectorSource({wrapX: true}));

        setIsInstantiated(true);
    },[map]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(!map || !vectorSource) return;

        setDrawBox(new Draw({
            source: vectorSource,
            type: 'Circle',
            geometryFunction: createBox(),
        }));

        setVectorLayer(new OLVectorLayer({
            source: vectorSource,
            style
        }));
    }, [vectorSource]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if(!map || !vectorLayer) return;

        map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
        vectorLayer.setZIndex(zIndex);

        if( canDraw )
        {
            map.addInteraction(drawBox);

            if( onShapeDrawn != null ) {
                drawBox.on('drawend', (e) => {
                    onShapeDrawn(e);
                })
            }
        }   

        return () => {
            if (map) {
                map.removeLayer(vectorLayer);
            }
        }
    }, [vectorLayer]);

    // update map if features prop changes
    useEffect( () => {
        if(!map || !vectorLayer) return;

        map.removeLayer(vectorLayer);
        vectorSource.clear();

        if (featureCollection?.features?.length) { // may be empty on first render
            vectorSource.addFeatures(new GeoJSON().readFeatures(featureCollection,
                {dataProjection:'EPSG:4326', featureProjection:'EPSG:4326'}));
        }

        map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
        vectorLayer.setZIndex(zIndex);
    }, [featureCollection])

    // Enable/Disable draw interaction when canDraw bool prop changes
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!map || !vectorLayer || !drawBox) return;

        console.log(`vector layer canDraw: ${canDraw}`);
        if( canDraw )
        {
            map.removeLayer(vectorLayer);

            map.addInteraction(drawBox);

            if( onShapeDrawn != null ) {
                drawBox.on('drawend', (e) => {
                    onShapeDrawn(e);
                })
            }

            map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
            vectorLayer.setZIndex(zIndex);
        } else {
            console.log('removing draw interaction');
            //map.getInteractions().pop();
            map.removeInteraction(drawBox);
        }
    }, [canDraw]);

    return null;
}

export default VectorLayer;
```

Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 2):

I think your vector layer is re-created on each render.

Put creation of the vectorLayer outside the component function or use a useMemo :

```
const vectorLayer = useMemo(()=> {
    let vectorSource = new VectorSource({wrapX: true});
    let vectorLayer = new OLVectorLayer({
        source: vectorSource,
        style
    });
    return vectorLayer
},  []);

Then use the vectorLayer to access the source.
```